# Can I run jrunscript from a JRE

Tags: java

The JDK has jrunscript executables.  Does the JRE have the needed jars that can be executed so as not to require a complete JDK to use jrunscript?

In other words, can I run jrunscript by calling the java executable with a class name.

Comment: I would hope so.  How many users do you know that have the full JDK downloaded on their computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JRunscript executables are nothing but javascript files. 
I do not know if you can directly use commandline with just jre installed but, You can definitely do it using a simple javaclass and running the javaclass from the commandline.

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

public class RunScriptFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
    try {
      FileReader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
      engine.eval(reader);
      reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

To compile (Required JDK):

```
javac RunScriptFile.java.
You'll get "RunScriptFile.class"
```

To Run (Requires JRE):

```
java RunScriptFile <myawesomescript.js>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: wait a minute... i thought you needed a rhino jar in your classpath. Are you saying that Java has a Javascript engine included?

Comment: Rhino is included in at least the JDK starting in Java 6.  My basic question is if it is included in the JRE.  Apparently that is the case.

Comment: This indeed allows me to execute my js.  Unfortunately I'm using some of the built in commands of jrunscript like mv and exec.

Answer (score 2):

jrunscript resides in com.sun.tools.script.shell.Main inside *tools.jar* on my JDK.

That file is apparently not bundled with the JRE

As someone already mentioned a small amount of java code can be used to launch your script instead:

```
new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js").eval(jsCode)
```

The special jrunscript functions such as ls(), mv(), echo() and read() are not in the JRE.

These functions are actually JavaScript functions defined in an init script [[see init.js from the openjdk repo]](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/dd7969318d7a/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/script/shell/init.js). That script is automatically loaded by jrunscript before your code.

You could copy these functions in your script. Just keep in mind that openjdk is licensed under the GPL.

Answer (score -1):

The JRE contains everything required run java programs, including any standard library jar files.

The JDK contains the tools and libraries required to write Java programs. So as long as you don't accidentally import implementation classes (such as stuff in `com.sum.*`) then you java program should run on any JRE of the correct version.